# Splitting a File without using a line count

Tags: python

So, basically, I have a large file that is made up of multiple, unequal parts where each part has an identical header. How would I code a python program that splits the file up into the parts using the header as the splitting point? I cannot use a line count because each part within the file are not of equal length.

Comment: Do you know in advance what that header is? Do you know it is a text file? Is the header a complete text line? Is the file too large to load into memory all at once? What have you tried?

Comment: I know what the header is in advance. It is multiple lines and yes it is a text file. I can simply do the splitting with a line count however, each part is not an equal amount of lines. I just need a way to split the file whenever the program reads the first line of the header and then write that part to a new file. The files also do not contain the same number of parts as well.

Comment: You did not answer my question about the file's size. If it is not too large to read into memory and to keep all the split files in memory, use Joran Beasley's answer (and accept that answer by clicking the checkmark at the top left of that answer). Let us know if the file's size makes that answer unsuitable for you.

Comment: Oh, sorry. The file in not too large to read into memory.I will try Joran's answer. It should work as all the program needs to do is write the split text to a new file and then move on to the next header and so on.

Comment: That is not what Joran's answer does. It makes a list where each member is the contents of a new file. After you do Joran's line you will need to write each member of the list to a file.

Answer (score 1):

i guess

```
parts = file_handle.read().split(header_text)
```